# I want the absolute value of a constant, the constant type is CLLocationDegrees

Tags: swift

I don't know how to resove the problem, I get the error on the fabs: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

```
 func isUpdateLocation(currentLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D, userLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D)-> Bool {

    let latitude: CLLocationDegrees = currentLocation.latitude - userLocation.latitude
    let longitude: CLLocationDegrees = currentLocation.longitude - userLocation.longitude

    let absoluteValueOfLatitude ＝ fabs(latitude)// the fabs I get the error :Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
    let absoluteValueOfLongitude = fabs(longitude)

    if latitude > 0.01 || longitude > 0.01 {

        return true
    }

    return false

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha,the problem is that you have typed a **different** equal operator.

```
// odd equal operator
let absoluteValueOfLatitude ＝ fabs(latitude)

// correct equal operator
let absoluteValueOfLatitude = fabs(latitude) 

// notice the difference with these two equal operator (＝ & =)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the global function `abs()`:

```
/// Return the absolute value of `x`.
///
/// Concrete instances of `SignedNumberType` can specialize this
/// function by conforming to `AbsoluteValuable`.
func abs<T : SignedNumberType>(x: T) -> T
```

So:

```
let absoluteValueOfLatitude = abs(latitude)
let absoluteValueOfLongitude = abs(longitude)
```